# Every package installed with pip is not found

Tags: bash, package-management, software-installation, python

On my pc, I can correctly install any package with pip without any errors.
But when I try to run it with its command I always get the same "command not found" error.
I have installed Python 3.10.

For example, this is what happens when I try to install quantumrandom (and every other programs):

```
pip install quantumrandom
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting quantumrandom
  Using cached quantumrandom-1.9.0.tar.gz (7.6 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for quantumrandom, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: quantumrandom
    Running setup.py install for quantumrandom ... done
Successfully installed quantumrandom-1.9.0

qrandom --int --min 5 --max 15
bash: qrandom: command not found
```

I believe that all packages installed with pip end up in this folder: "/home/tommaso/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages"

This is the output of "python -m site":

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/tommaso/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/tommaso/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/tommaso/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

And this is my PATH variable:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; which provide the best clue as to what software stack you're using & how the python3 version you're using relates.

Comment: Try adding the following to `~/.bashrc` and either source this file or reboot: `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages` This is an oddity that I have encountered with Python 3.10 on my own system...

Comment: @andrew.46 If you look at the last few lines in `~/.profile` you'll see the conditional statement that automatically adds the path.

Comment: @andrew.46 So really, the problem is with the system path, not the python path.

Comment: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/python-3-10-0-problems-with-pipx-4175702100/

Answer (score 6):

**All you have to do is log out and log back in.** The directory pip installs to is not in your path but when you log back in, your path will be automatically updated.

To explain: `pip` installs the executable files at `$HOME/.local/bin` . There is a conditional statement in `~/.profile` (at the end of the file) that automatically adds this directory to your PATH, if and only if it exists:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

When you logged in, before you installed your first pip packages, this directory did not exist so it is not currently in your path.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike as an other commenter said, **you *don't* need to log out and log back in**. Just run this command:

```
source ~/.profile
```

To explain: `source` executes a script in the current shell. Your `~/.profile` file has a couple of lines (see in other mchid's comment) that adds your private bin (where Python installs pip binaries) to your PATH variable.